# Calliing factory function in controllers of angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource, angular-controller

I am getting rest api call from angular service and I need to get the response data in any variable of angular controller.So yhat I can use that in view file.
Here is my code:

my angular service.js:

```
  angular.module('customerdetails').factory('Detail',['$resource', 
     function($resource){
       return new Customerdetails($resource);
  }]);

  function Customerdetails( resource ) {                         
     this.getUsers = function( scope ) {
       var Customerdetails = resource('/customerdetails');
       Customerdetails.query(function(users){       
           scope.Customerdetails = users;
       });
     }
  }
```

my angular controller:

```
  angular.module('customerdetails').controller('CustomerController', 
    ['$scope', '$rootScope',  'Authentication', 'Detail', 
    function ($scope,   $rootScope, Authentication, Detail) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
        $scope.users = [];

        $scope.find = function(){
        Detail.getUsers( $scope ) 
          .success(function (custs) {
                $scope.customers = custs;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            });

        //console.log(users,"ppppppp");
       };
      } ]);
```

In this I get details in my restapi.When i need to get data from controller inorder to pass in view file(html),it shows Detail.getUsers is not defined.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('customerdetails').factory('Detail',['$resource', 
  var  getUsers = function(resource) {
    console.log('getUsers')
  };

  return {
    getUsers : getUsers
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks,,I have tried this but showing  error in "['$resporce', var'  SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'
 var  getUsers = function($resource) {

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered such like issues before. My solution was to combine factories and services. Like so:

```
//Factory
angular.module('customerdetails').factory('Detail',['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/customerdetails');
}]);

// Service
angular.module('customerdetails').service('DetailService', ['Detail', function (Detail) {
    this.getUsers = function(success, error){
        return Detail.query().$promise.then(success).catch(error);
    }    
}]);
```

From here, you can inject your service in the controller.

```
// Controller
angular.module('customerdetails').controller('CustomerController',['$scope', '$rootScope',  'Authentication', 'DetailService', function ($scope,   $rootScope, Authentication, DetailService) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.users = [];

    $scope.find = function(){
        DetailService.getUsers(function(custs){
            $scope.customers = custs;
        }, function(error){
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
        });
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks murwa,i have tried this but showing the following error"Error: Detail.query(...).$promise.then(...).error is not a function"

Comment: hi ,its working now,thanks murwa...but  i didnt able to get my response date in the variable of angular controller,